# Macro to do nothing via a \def

Tags: macros, expansion

I have encountered another expansion issue and have narrowed it down to this simple test case of a macro that does *nothing*, well at least it tries to do nothing, but is not all that successful.

If I declare this macro as:

```
\newcommand*{\DoNothingA}[1]{#1}%
```

This works great, no surprises there.

However, if this macros is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\DoNothingB}[1]{% 
    \def\Temp{#1}%
    \Temp%
}%
```

then, this has problems where there is an attempt to use this in an `\edef`.

### Output:

Note that the MWE below yields a compile error for the last step, so you need to hit <kbd>`<RETURN>`</kbd> to skip past it to see the output (or comment out the last `\edef`, but then this won't show Question 2 below).

The MWE below yields the following:

[image]

The last line being especially curious as it produced `foo 4`, and was the result of:

```
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 5}}
\NewTemp
\color{red}% Highlight problem output
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 6}}
\NewTemp 
\color{black}
~-- used \verb|\edef| to store output of macro
```

### Questions:

1. What is the explanation of the expansion issue here?
2. How does the final output become `foo 4` (`foo 5` would have been easier to accept), if we skip past the compile error?
3. Since David Carlisle has been quoted as saying that ["a few extra `\expandafter` cure all known ills"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44990/4301) :-), what is the sequence of `\expandafter`s needed in the last `\edef` to use macro `\DoNothinB` as defined here.
4. How can I adjust the `\DoNothingB{}` macro to use a temp variable and still work in the three cases in the MWE (preferrably without having to use any `\expandafter` trickery.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% To highlight problem output

\newcommand*{\DoNothingA}[1]{#1}% Does everything I want in all cases

\newcommand*{\DoNothingB}[1]{% Works mostly, except if used in a \edef
    \def\Temp{#1}%
    \Temp%
}%

\begin{document}
% These two work great.
\DoNothingA{foo 1}
\DoNothingB{foo 2}
-- used output of macro directly

% These two also work great.
\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 3}}
\NewTemp
\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 4}}
\NewTemp
~-- used \verb|\def| to store output of macro


\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 5}}
\NewTemp
\color{red}% Highlight problem output
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 6}}
%\show\NewTemp% Excellent suggestion by David Carlisle yields: \def foo 4{foo 6}foo 4
\NewTemp 
\color{black}
~-- used \verb|\edef| to store output of macro
% Why is the last output "foo 4" (after ignoring error)??
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can't use assignments like `\def` or `\edef` inside expandable contexts like `\edef` because they are not expandable!

**Long answer:**
An `\edef` expands its content until only non-expandable tokens are left (note that text is not expandable). `\def` is an assignment and all assignments must be *executed* and are therefore not *expandable*. Your `\DoNothingB` actually does something: it defines `\Temp`!

Let me explain what happens on the following example:

```
\def\Temp{before}
% ...
\edef\NewTemp{\def\Temp{something}}
```

then the `\edef` tries to expand first `\def` which is not expandable and therefore stays at it is, then `\temp` which is expanded to `before` and then the rest: the tokens `{`, `s`, `o`, ..., `g`, and `}`, which are all not expandable either. Therefore you get `\NewTemp` as `\def before{something}` which will instruct TeX, once `\NewTemp` is expanded, i.e. used, to define `b` with the parameter text `efore` and the replacement text `something`. Because `b` is immutable (as long it is not declared an active character) you will get an error here.

In your example `\Temp` has been define to `foo 4` in your fourth example, where you use `\DoNothingB` outside of an `\edef`. In the next usage inside of an `\edef` (`\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 6}}`) you get `\def foo4{foo 6}foo4` for `\NewTemp` because both `\Temp` usage are expanded right then, which leads to the above mentioned error. The `\def foo4{foo 6}` is discarded as part of the error handling and then `foo4` is typeset. If `\Temp` would be defined differently before the output would be accordantly.

A few `\expandafter`s don't help you here because the order is not the issue here and `\edef` expands anyway everything continuously until only non-expandable tokens remain.

However, you might want to add some `\noexpand` direct before the `\Temp` macros inside `\DoNothingB` to protect them from premature expansion in the first `\edef`. This now doesn't work inside a `\def`. Normally you can use `\protect` with LaTeX's `\protected@edef` instead. Depending on the context `\protect` is either `\relax` (outside `\protected@edef`) or `\@unexpandable@protect` (inside `\protected@edef`) which is similar to `\noexpand`. For usage with `\def` you need to test this mode by yourself and add a `\noexpand` manually if inside `edef`.

The following code does this. Note that you need to replace all `\edef`s with `\protected@edef` for this to work. The normal `\edef` and other expanding contexts like `\message` or `\write` will not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% To highlight problem output

\newcommand*{\DoNothingA}[1]{#1}% Does everything I want in all cases

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DoNothingB}[1]{% Works mostly, except if used in a \edef
    \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        \def\noexpand\Temp{#1}%
    \else
        \def\Temp{#1}%
    \fi
    \protect\Temp%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% These two work great.
\DoNothingA{foo 1}
\DoNothingB{foo 2}
-- used output of macro directly

% These two also work great.
\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 3}}
\NewTemp
\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 4}}
\NewTemp
~-- used \verb|\def| to store output of macro


\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 5}}
\NewTemp
\color{red}% Highlight problem output
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 6}}
\makeatother
\NewTemp 
\color{black}
~-- used \verb|\edef| to store output of macro
% Why is the last output "foo 4" (after ignoring error)??
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\newcommand*{\DoNothingA}[1]{#1}

\newcommand*{\DoNothingB}[1]{\def\Temp{#1}\Temp}

\begin{document}

\DoNothingA{foo 1}
\DoNothingB{foo 2}
```

According to the definitions this prints "foo 1" and "foo 2" and defines `\Temp` to expand to `foo 2`

```
\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 3}}
\NewTemp
```

This defines `\NewTemp` to expand to `\DoNothingA{foo 3}`, so `\NewTemp` prints "foo 3"

```
\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 4}}
\NewTemp
```

This does

```
\DoNothingB{foo 4}
```

which defines `\Temp` to expand to `foo 4` and prints "foo 4"

```
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingA{foo 5}}
\NewTemp
```

Let's go slowly here. The `\edef` causes the expansion of `\DoNothingA`, which finds it argument and is replaced by its replacement text; all is eventually equivalent to saying

```
\def\NewTemp{foo 5}
```

Now the fun begins.

```
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo 6}}
```

Here `\DoNothingB` finds its argument and is replaced by

```
\def\Temp{foo 6}\Temp
```

but `\edef` is not satisfied and replaces both instances of `\Temp` by its replacement text, which is still `foo 4` and so TeX executes the equivalent of

```
\def\NewTemp{\def foo4{foo 6}foo 4}
```

and now the call

```
\NewTemp
```

will try doing

```
\def foo4{foo 6}foo 4
```

The result is an error message: since no control sequence follows `\def`, TeX inserts `\inaccessible` and performs

```
\def\inaccessible foo4{foo 6}foo 4
```

which results in printing "foo 4" after having defined the `\inaccessible` control sequence.

So there are the answers to 1 and 2. The answers to 3 and 4 are easy: you can't perform an assignment during an `\edef`, with any number of `\expandafter`s, because TeX doesn't perform assignments during expansion, but only at a later stage of processing. In summary: you can't change the meaning of a control sequence while doing an `\edef`.

### Workaround

If you want to feed `\DoNothingB` in an `\edef` you have to decide what it's supposed to do in that case. If you simply want that it does nothing special with respect to being inside a `\def` then

```
\protected\def\Temp{} % initialization
\newcommand*\DoNothingB[1]{\protected\def\Temp{#1}\Temp}
```

might do; if you say

```
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo}}
```

this would expand `\DoNothingB` resulting in the token list

```
\protected\def\Temp{foo}\Temp
```

but now all tokens are unexpandable and so the `\edef` would be equivalent to

```
\def\NewTemp{\protected\def\Temp{foo}\Temp}
```

In case of `\def\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo}}` a call of `\NewTemp` would do the same as before after the first expansion step. Note that it's necessary to initialize `\Temp` to be a `\protected` macro, otherwise something like

```
\edef\NewTemp{\DoNothingB{foo}}
```

would result in an error message about "Undefined control sequence".

Of course, this is under the assumption that the argument to `\DoNothingB` is made of unexpandable tokens, as they wouldn't be protected against expansion.